How to expose hooks to @wordpress/hooks?
I'm trying to hook into wp_handle_upload_prefilter with JavaScript, but I must be doing it wrong.
Here's my code:
add_action(
    'admin_enqueue_scripts',
    'enqueue_backend_scripts',
);
public function enqueue_backend_scripts( $page ) {

    if ($page !== 'upload.php') {
        return;
    }

    $script_assets = require get_build_path( 'my-script.asset.php' );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'prefix-my-script',
        get_build( 'my-script.js' ),
        $script_assets['dependencies'],
        '0.1.0',
        true
    );
}

import { addFilter } from '@wordpress/hooks';

console.log( 'foo' );

addFilter( 'all', 'my-namespace', ( e ) => console.log( 'bar', e ) );


According to the documentation the 'all-hook' is for debugging, and should trigger all filters – however in my case nothing happens, except the 'foo' console log. I've tried some different namespaces, but I don't think that is the issue. Is there another library I need to load as a dependency, and does @wordpress/hooks even work outside the block editor?

the documentation starts with "In non-minified builds". have you set that ? e.g. with define("SCRIPT_DEBUG", TRUE);.

You’ve completely misunderstood how that package works. You can’t use it to hook PHP hooks from JavaScript. There’s no conceivable way that could even work. That package lets you use hooks in JavaScript, but only for hooks defined and executed in JavaScript.

That makes sense @JacobPeattie, thanks for clearing that up.  However why are no JavaScript hooks called with 'all'? Are there no native JS hooks? I've set SCRIPT_DEBUG to true.
